# How can I change the value of a column based of the vales of two other columns in the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `Loan`, containing, along other columns, the `LoanDate`, `ReturnDate` and `Expired`. The first two are datetime, whereas the latter is a bit.

What should I do if, the `getutcdate()` is over the `ReturnDate` value, the `Expired` column updates itself automatically to 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want the `Expired` column became automatically `1` when current date is over `ReturnDate`.

In that case you can use a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table) for `Expired`:

```
create table Loan (
  LoanDate datetime null,
  ReturnDate datetime null,
  Expired as cast(case when getutcdate()>ReturnDate then 1 else 0 end as bit)
)
```

This works fine for simple computations that use data from the same row like this one.

Note that computed columns are 'read only', you omit then from `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements:

```
insert into Loan (LoanDate, ReturnDate) values
  ('20010101','20011231'),
  ('20210101','20211231')
```

Comment: Side note: although this works fine for computations that only use data from the current the row, I do not recommend using computed columns for calling functions that use data from other tables, as it would slow the queries.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot!